# Alert view center changes when another view is presented on root view

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, ios12

In the app, I'm showing an alert when there is no **internet connection** (Showing on root view controller). There is a `Biometric authentication` on the application too. So whenever Biometric page appears (Biometric page also shows on root view controller) on the top of the `alertview` and removes that from the view, alert view **constraints** changes and doesn't show in the middle.

**Step 1:-**

**Shows Error message**

[image]

**Showing alert Code :-**

```
  func showAlert(title:String, message: String, buttons: [UIAlertAction]) {
    // create the alert
    self.alert.title = title
    self.alert.message = message

    // add an action (button)
    if buttons.count == 0 {
        self.alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    } else {
        for i in 0...buttons.count-1 {
            self.alert.addAction(buttons[i])
        }
    }
    self.viewController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Step 2:-**

Exit the application and shows the biometric verification view.

**App Delegate File :-**

```
   func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if self.userToken != "" && self.biometricStatus && !UserAccessTemp.isBiometricActive {

        let controller = BiometricCheckViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .BiometricCheck)
        if let window = self.window, let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
            var currentController = rootViewController
            while let presentedController = currentController.presentedViewController {
                currentController = presentedController
            }
            currentController.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    }
```

[image]

**Step 3:-**

Alert View alignment changes after dismiss the biometric verification view

[image]

So how can I re-center the alert view after the Biometric view dismiss?

Comment: There may be alternative way to think about it.. If you want to present your biometric view controller on top of everything you have running in your app without disturbing it, you can create a new window to present that use makeKeyAndVisible() to switch between your windows.

Comment: Your comment just helps me to figure it out my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put `makeKeyAndVisible()` to the Biometric view, and it does fix the problem. Thanks to the Deepika's comment.

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if self.userToken != "" && self.biometricStatus && !UserAccessTemp.isBiometricActive {

        let controller = BiometricCheckViewController.instantiate(fromAppStoryboard: .BiometricCheck)

        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
func showAlert(title:String, message: String, buttons: [UIAlertAction]) {
    // create the alert
    self.alert.title = title
    self.alert.message = message

    // add an action (button)
    if buttons.count == 0 {
        self.alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    } else {
        for i in 0...buttons.count-1 {
            self.alert.addAction(buttons[i])
        }
    }

    if var topController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }

        topController.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```